# @ConfigurationProperties, @Value not Working YET Passing the Tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I have a strange problem reading configuration, none of solutions I've seen seem to work. Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my properties class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyProperties {
    private String host;
    private int port;
}
```

I then use MyProperties class in my class using @Autowired:

```
@Autowired
private MyProperties props;
```

However, I'm getting null for my **props** object.

Strangely, this is **passing the tests just perfectly**:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties props;
    
    @Test
    void test_configuration() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(props.getHost(), "xx.xx.xx.xx");//pass!
        Assertions.assertEquals(props.getPort(), xxxxxx);//pass!
    }
}
```

It has totally refused to work, and so has @Value injection. What could I be missing?

**EDIT**

Here's complete code of how I'm using @Autowired on MyProperties (I've included @Value which is also not working)

```
@Slf4j
@Component //also tried @Configurable, @Service
public class MyService {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties props;
    
    @Value("localhost")
    public String host;
    
    public void post() {
        log.info(host + props);// =null and null
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

However, I've noticed that on the controller, it works perfectly okay:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@Service
public class Main {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties props;
    
    @Value("localhost")
    private String host;
    
    @GetMapping("/post")
    public void post() {
        log.info(host + props);//=it's perfect!
        new MyService().post();// calling MyService - where @Autowired or @Value is failing
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us more code about where you autowire the props? Just to make sure this isn't a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null.

Comment: @g00glen00b added some code; tried suggestions from the answers in the link you shared, problem still there. HOWEVER, in RestController, it works perfectly. (and in tests)

Comment: How do you interact with `MyService`? Can you show that code too (where you call `myService.post()`).

Comment: @g00glen00b I've showed on RestController example code

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because the `MyService` you're using isn't a Spring bean, but an instance you created by yourself (using `new MyService()`).

To make this work, you should autowire `MyService`, in stead of creating your own instance:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class Main {
    @Autowired // Autowire MyService
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping("/post")
    public void post() {
        myService.post(); // Use the myService field
    }
}
```

For more information, look at this Q&A: [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null).

Comment: That just did it! - Autowiring MyService. I'm still learning Spring. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

**`new MyService()`** is not a "spring bean", thus can't be auto-wired with anything!;)

##### 1. Lombok

> Some people use Project Lombok to add getters and setters automatically. **Make sure that Lombok does not generate any particular constructor for such a type**, as it is used automatically by the container to instantiate the object.

With "such a type" `ConfigurationProperties` is referred in [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) (one of my favorite chapters;) More Exact: [2.8.1. JavaBean properties binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding), at the *bottom* of second "Note!" ;)

So this could be a reason (for strange behavior).

Comment: You were right, new MyService() is not a Spring bean; I had to autowire it. Thank you for the references too.